# PrimaryKeyRelatedField fields prints ids of foreign table but need values

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

PrimaryKeyRelatedField fields prints ids of foreign table but api demands to return values. Is there any customized way to get the values

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    
        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('album', 'order')
            order_by = 'order'

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Results :

```
{
    'album_name': 'The Roots',
    'artist': 'Undun',
    'tracks': [
        89,
        90,
        91,
        ...
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to get output in the below format:

```
{
        'album_name': 'The Roots',
        'artist': 'Undun',
        'tracks': [
            {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
            {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
            {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other way and not least is using `depth` option.

> The default ModelSerializer uses primary keys for relationships, but
>   you can also easily generate nested representations using the depth
>   option:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
        depth = 1
```

> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the
>   depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a
>   flat representation.

Meaning if one of your field `e.g. (Track)` has a child foreign model you can also use `depth = 2` to serialize that level of relation.

You can learn more about this in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

Comment: what if I have another table PlayingSites which has one to one relation with Tracks and I need all the results in single Json in restful api

Comment: When you read my answer you can set the depth level based on how many level of relations you want to serialized the result.

Comment: in other ways if you want to have a fullcontrol of your serializer you can define by modelSerializer just like @Alasdair pointed.

Comment: But in the AlbumSeriliazer fields I cannot set Playsites Information it throws me error

Comment: All you have to do is to add the field (PlayingSites ) to your TrackSerializer fields option since it is related and not the with Album

Comment: I had tried that , I miss typed in the class Models.It works like charm. Thanks a lot for a help . You saved me .

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive this by creating a serializer for the `track` field. See the example for [nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) in the rest frameworks docs:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```